# Unable to add primary key to innodb table without one

Tags: mysql, primary-key, mysql-5.7

I've inherited myself a fun table with some peculiar indexes (and no primary key) on it, that looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_wonky_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `login` varchar(127) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_1` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_2` varchar(127) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_4` varchar(127) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val_5` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `my_wonky_table_id_idx` (`id`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_timestamp_idx` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_val_1_idx` (`val_1`,`id`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_val_2_idx` (`val_2`,`id`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_val_4_idx` (`val_4`,`id`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_val_5_idx` (`val_5`,`id`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_ip_idx` (`ip`(16),`id`),
  KEY `my_wonky_table_login_idx` (`login`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (`id`)
(PARTITION pdefault VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Now, because it has no primary key, nor a fully unique index, MySQL adds a `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` (that's taking up quite some space, but that's a different matter).

Note that even though there is a column called `id`, it's not actually a unique entry. For this reason, I want to add an (auto incremented) column, that, combined with the `id` column, should act as the primary key.

However, I appear to be unable to add an auto_incremented column; I suspect this is because of the 'secret' column MySQL adds, because of the error message saying I already have an auto-incremented column, even though I don't believe I do.

The following:

```
ALTER TABLE my_wonky_table 
    ADD COLUMN count SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, count);
```

yields:

```
ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an auto-Incrementing column, as long as there is an index (key) on it, to fix this issue you need to execute those commands:

```
ALTER TABLE my_wonky_table ADD COLUMN count SMALLINT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE my_wonky_table ADD INDEX (count);
ALTER TABLE my_wonky_table CHANGE count count SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE my_wonky_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, count);
```

Comment: You can do it in one statement: `ALTER TABLE my_wonky_table ADD COLUMN count SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD INDEX (count), ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, count) ;`

Comment: Or (with different indexing): `ALTER TABLE my_wonky_table ADD COLUMN count SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD PRIMARY KEY (count, id) ;`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I know, sorry about that, but I used to give tutorials to new employee, one command per statement, still have the old habit.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the "hidden PK" that is in the way.  `ALTER TABLE ... ADD PRIMARY KEY(...)` will replace it.  The problem is that the "partition key", `id` in your case, must be part of every `UNIQUE` key, and the PK is `UNIQUE`.

It is more efficient to do all `ALTERs` in a single statement.  (There are a few exceptions.)

```
ALTER TABLE my _wonky_table
    ADD COLUMN count SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY(count, id);
```

`count SMALLINT` for the PK:

- You are not expecting more than 32K rows in the table?  In general you should not use `PARTITIONing` on a table with fewer than 1M rows.
- Don't you want `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`?
- "count" is an unusual name for the AI; that, plus having `id` not be the AI, will confuse readers; please rethink both column names.

"Index prefixing" is rarely good.  Recommend removing "(16)".

```
KEY `my_wonky_table_ip_idx` (`ip`(16),`id`)
```

Do you really have only one partition?  If so, why partition at all?

Let's see some of the `SELECTs`; we can discuss the utility (or lack of) of the indexes.

Comment: You're correct. I misunderstood how auto increment works. What I actually wanted was a count column that increments for each duplicate id occurrence, because id in this table is not unique. But this does not appear to be possible. If I add an auto increment column as described above, I would need to set it to bigint, as I have more than 5 billion rows, but I'm not sure whether that's better or worse than the current hidden key that MySQL uses. Prefix  index is to be removed, I encountered a wonky bug with that a while ago. Partitioning is done by month, the timestamp is also in the id value.

Comment: MyISAM (deprecated) had the trick of a `AUTO_INCREMENT` as the second column of the PK.  It is possible (though clumsy) to simulate such.  5B - `BIGINT` - OK.  The hidden key is 6 bytes, but has several caveats, so I reluctantly recommend the larger 8-byte `BIGINT`.

Comment: Your `id` is a timestamp concatenated with something else?  And the second part does not "dedup" sufficiently?  If it did, then `id` could be the PK.  And can you deduce `timestamp` by splitting `id`?  With 5B rows, shrinking the disk footprint is an important task.

Comment: Since each secondary key has the primary key implicitly added, we are talking about 6b / 8b / etc.  But if `id` could be the PK, then it would be moving from +6b to +0b, thereby saving something like 300GB of disk space.

Comment: The `timestamp` column has the exact same value as the one that's inside `id`. The timestamp bitshifted 32 bits to the left. The column was simply kept for convenience, but now takes up quite some space. Adding a column is almost a no-go, as it seems like it will take too long. A lot of the secondary keys could be added into a big compound key, which shaves off a lot of space. But the problem with no primary key appears to be staying for a while.

Comment: Combining indexes?  Be careful.  `INDEX(a,b,id)` is _not_ the same as `INDEX(a,id), INDEX(b,id)`; order _does_ matter.  [_More discussion_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .

Comment: Very true, I'm still looking at the queries, but they appear to be quite bunched up at the moment. The application that generates the queries is a bit strange, I'm still figuring out what `SELECT`s come out of it. Initial benchmarks seem promising, though.

Comment: Consider using the slowlog to identify the slow `SELECTs`.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, query speed is not an issue. The indexes are simply growing too rapidly, which is what I wanted to reduce using a primary key and compound indexes. Slow query log was helpful in getting a big set of queries to benchmark against, though.

Comment: If `id` starts with a `timestamp`, then `id` would probably be quite adequate for chunking, as I just now recommended in your other question.