# How does MySQL decide what partitions to load into memory?

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.6, partitioning, memory

I have a server where the MySQL indexes won't fit into memory (2TB total index, 512GB RAM on machine), and am wondering how MySQL decides what parts to put into memory and what not.

The relevant tables are range partitioned on ID, and I'm told (but can't find anything proving this) that the last 3 months is available in memory.

I'm hoping there's a more substantial answer available somewhere.

Comment: Assuming you are using InnoDB, see [The InnoDB Buffer Pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html). Generally speaking, frequently accessed (parts of) data and indexes stay in the cache. Partitioning by ID will probably not help you to seperate old and new data. Also make sure your configuration fits your server specs. If you never heard about the buffer pool and set up the server, you probably didn't change the default values. The mysql default values are made for servers with 500MB ram. If you have 1000 times that much, you might be missing some potential here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoDB's "buffer_pool" contains *blocks* that are kept there in (roughly) a "least recently used" order.  That is, when you touch a block for either reading or writing, it is pulled into the buffer_pool and marked as "most recently used".  If there was not room for this block, then the "least recently used" block was first removed from the buffer_pool.

`PARTITIONing` has nothing to do with the caching scheme.  In particular, partitioning by the `PRIMARY KEY` is almost always useless, and almost always redundant with letting the caching (described above) happen.

If you would like to discuss performance improvements, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the slow query.

Using `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` is an excellent use of partitioning, but only because it makes dropping "old" data *very* efficient.  Note: I did not say `BY RANGE(id)`.

Even if the math is correct, you may or may not have "the last 3 months" cached in RAM -- if someone scanned stuff from 4 months ago, someblocks would have to be bump to allow for that scan.  Then the 4-month-old bllcks would clutter the buffer_pool until they get bumped out.

**Update**

Since you have a "mission critical" system that must accept writes all the time, and have no `PRIMARY KEY`, you need some drastic action.  Here's what I would do.

I would back up into the code.  If there is not already code between the "users" and the database, I would start by building such a layer and force the "users" to call an API that say "write ... to the database".

To start with, the API would simply do an `INSERT` like the original code.  This has minimal impact.

Then I would prepare new code, wherein the API has more complex code behind it.  In particular, it would be writing to the existing table *and* the new table (with `PRIMARY KEY`, new index(es), changed datatypes, `PARTITIONing`, etc).

Meanwhile, another script would be copying, in chunks, the existing data from the existing table to the new table.  (This is part of what `pt-online-schema-change` does, but we will take some liberties.)

I suggest chunk size of 1000 rows, each chunk as a its own 'transaction' (assuming you are a using InnoDB).  The chunking should follow some index, whichever one closes to being unique.  (An yes/no column would be poor because you could not get more than 2 chunks.)

When all finished, you will have two copies of the data; you can test before dropping the old table.

Reads can proceed unchanged during the process because the old table remains intact.

Some blogs with tips:

- [Altering a huge table](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/alterhuge)
- [Chunking](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks)
- [Partitioning](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)
- [Don't use OFFSET](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

Comment: Interesting. Does the buffer pool contain both data and indexes? And if so, does MySQL use the same LRU algorithm to decide what subtrees of the indexes to put into the pool? I have a rather strange (in relational database terms) table, with the id column being a bigint containing the timestamp (and some other values) bit shifted into it, to partition by. The table has no primary key (only indexes, not even unique), which in hindsight appears to be a horrible mistake, as we now have a huge GEN_CLUST_INDEX.

Comment: Both data and index - yes.  In fact the data's BTree and a secondary index's BTree look virtually identical.  Each is a collection of 16KB blocks cached via the buffer_pool on an "equal" basis.  To the buffer_pool and LRU, it's just a bunch of blocks.

Comment: @Aeveus - you did a good job of separating this question from [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164259/unable-to-add-primary-key-to-innodb-table-without-one); I am only now noticing that both belong to the same Asker.

Comment: There appear to be quite some issues with this table, and at first I wasn't sure what was causing what problem. I'm sure many issues remain, but being able to slowly tackle them helps.

Comment: Take a look at `pt-online-schema-change`.  It is a tool for modifying a large table without a long downtime.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a peek. One of the big issues is that I can't really take the database down, and that most of tools require a PK (that most of these tables don't have).

Comment: Oops; I forgot about that requirement.  That, to me, is a strong argument for having an explicit PK.  Can you avoid writing to a particular table for an hour?  I'm thinking of ways to "alter" a table by copying, as long as there aren't any updates during the process.  In particular, [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) discusses a chunked copy that will work without a PK -- 1. create desired schema; 2. stop writes; 3. chunked copy to new; 4. `RENAME TABLE` to swap into place; 5. allow writes.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's a so-called 'mission critical' system. One that's designed without the possibility of taking a database down and having another take over... The same with the applications writing to the table. I was able to copy a different  table by creating a new table (copy of the old one, with different indexes), and copying data over in chunks, and swapping tables afterwards. Had to do a check in the end to get data that was written in the old table during the migration. It's fine if data can't be read for a while, but it should always be written.

Comment: I added a lot more to my Answer.

Comment: Many thanks for the expanded answer, Rick! Unfortunately (.. yet again) I can't simply change the code and have it write into the new database; the application that inserts data (we only insert and select, no update/delete) is not hot-swappable, and rebooting it with a new version *will* result in loss of data. For some reason during the system design stage, it was decided to have the application directly write to the database, without anything in between. New layers are being built, but won't be deployed any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not load the data to memory while storing. It will load the result set of the query to Query cache only when query issued. If the same query is issued again, it will fetch from Query cache. This is applicable for both  partitioned or non-partitioned tables.

Comment: If a table is written to a lot, the Query cache is a burden and should be turned off.

Comment: Virtually all writes are of the form of read-modify-write, leaving the _block_ in memory.  That involves caches _other than_ the Query cache.